# Construct $K=\{ (a+bi)+(c+di)\sqrt{2} \}$ with Extension Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Construct $K=\{ (a+bi)+(c+di)\sqrt{2} \}$ with Extension Fields. where $i=\sqrt{-1}$. Can take it for granted that K is a field where degree is 4.
*construct K and confirm its degree*

---

we need irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}$ where the solution for x is $i,\sqrt{2}$.

For $i$, $x^2+1=0$. For $\sqrt{2}$, $x^2-2$

**First Extension]** Now, let $F=\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2+1)$. The elements of F are polynomials of degree at most 1 that is $$F=\{[a+bx]:a,b\in\mathbb{Q} \}=\{[a+bi]:a,b\in\mathbb{Q} \}$$ since $[x]=[i]$. Also $[F:K]=deg(x^2+1)=2$

**Second Extension]** Consider $S=F/(x^2-2)$

$\vdots$

***Missing*** *Cant really explain it in words*

$$S=\{(a+bi)+(c+di)\sqrt{2} :a,b,c,d  \mathbb{Q} \}$$
$[S:F]=deg(x^2-2)=2$.

Also $[S:K]=[S:F][F:K]=2*2=4$ which confirms the degree

---

**Have the intuition in missing steps. But could use some help.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field is given by $K=\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2})$. We can construct it from $\mathbb{Q}$ by a quadratic extension $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ with minimal polynomial $x^2-2$, and then again a quadratic extension $K=L(i)$ with minimal polynomial $x^2+1$.
Since clearly $i\notin\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, we have
$$
[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},i):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}]=2.
$$
Now we can use the dimension formula:
$$
[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},i):\mathbb{Q}]
=
[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},i):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}]\cdot
[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}]
=2\cdot2=4.
$$
No more intuition is needed, I think.